# How to evaluate the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\Bigl(1+2^x\Bigr)^{\frac{1}{x}}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I stumbled across this limit question and i'm not sure of how to handle this.

> $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\Bigl(1+2^x\Bigr)^{\frac{1}{x}}$

I think this limit goes to 1 because $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}=0$. Is this correct way to solve this limit?

Comment: There are no $n$ in the expressions.

Comment: Assuming you mean $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} (1+2^x)^{1/x}$$ the correct answer is $2$, because $1+2^x$ is approximately $2$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$, so then you have $(2^x)^{1/x}$

Comment: Intuitively, as $x\to\infty$, there's not much difference between $2^x+1$ and $2^x$, so we expect the limit to be $\left(2^x\right)^{1/x}=2$.  Now translate that to a formal calculation.

Comment: You can also take the log of the original expression and apply L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: What's the difference between $(1+2^x)^{1/x}$ and $(2^x)^{1/x}$ ?

Answer (score 3):

The function $\ln$ is continuous in the interval $(0,\infty)$, so
$$\ln\lim_{x\to\infty}(1+2^x)^{1/x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(1+2^x)}x=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2^x\ln 2}{1+2^x}=\ln 2$$

Then
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(1+2^x)^{1/x}=2$$

Comment: More generally
$$
\lim_{p \to \infty}\left(a^p+b^p\right)^{1/p} = \max\{|a|,|b|\}
$$
Thus (in more advanced mathematics) we say that the $l^\infty$ norm is the limit of the $l^p$ norm when $p \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $k>2$ be an arbitrary real number. Then for $x$ large enough*, we have
$$
2^x\leq 1+2^x\leq k^x
$$
Now take the $x$th root of all of them, giving
$$
2\leq \left(1 + 2^x\right)^{1/x}\leq k
$$
So for any $k>2$, eventually $\left(1 + 2^x\right)^{1/x}$ lies between $2$ and $k$. In other words, we have that for any $k>2$, there is a real number $X$ such that
$$
\left|2- \lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1 + 2^x\right)^{1/x}\right|\leq k-2
$$
for any $x>X$, showing that the limit exists and is equal to $2$.

---

*We have
$$
1+2^x\leq k^x\\
2^{-x} + 1\leq \left(\frac k2\right)^x
$$
Any positive $x$ that makes $2<\left(\frac k2\right)^x$ must fulfill the above inequality. We get
$$
\ln 2<x(\ln k-\ln 2)\\
\frac{\ln 2}{\ln k - \ln 2}< x
$$
so with $X = \frac{\ln 2}{\ln k - \ln 2}$ any $x>\max(X, 0)$ will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

No, it certainly is not correct, as it lacks of rigour. $\infty^0$ is an indeterminate form.

You can proceed like this: determine the limit of the log first and use *equivalence* of functions:
$$\ln(1+2x)^{\tfrac 1x}=\frac{\ln(1+2^x)}x\sim_\infty\frac{\ln(2^x)}x=\frac{\not x\ln2}{\not x}=\ln 2.$$
Indeed, $\;1+2^x\sim_\infty 2^x$, hence $\ln(1+2^x)\sim_\infty \ln(2^x)$.

Comment: Ahahahah :-)...

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is wrong. $\dfrac1x$ does tend to $0$, but you ignore the fact that $x$ goes to infinity at the same time. (You might as well have said the limit is infinity because $x$ goes to infinity.)

A correct way is to decompose

$$(1+2^x)^{1/x}=2\left(\frac1{2^x}+1\right)^{1/x}.$$

Now the quantity between parenthesis tends to $1$, and so does its $x^{th}$ root.